# How to set the rendering order of here maps groups with z-index

Tags: javascript, z-index, here-api

I am having a map with two groups added, each containing multiple markers, and want the first of them always be rendered above the second.

The map is using the here 3.1 core and i already tried to set the zIndex property in the opt_options parameter for each group without any effect. Markers can be deleted or added to each group at any time.

This is how i create and add the groups to the map:

```
const group1 = new H.map.Group({zIndex: 10});
const group2 = new H.map.Group({zIndex: 0});

map.addObjects([
    group1,
    group2
]);
```

Now at any time a marker can be added to one of the groups via a subscription:

```
poiMarkers$.subscribe(pois => {
    group1.removeAll();

    pois.forEach(poi => {
        const marker = new H.map.Marker(poi.position, poi.icon);
        group1.addObject(marker);
    }) 
});

userMarker$.subscribe(user => {
    group2.removeAll();

    const marker = new H.map.Marker(user.position, user.icon);
    group2.addObject(marker);
});
```

Now all markers are shown correctly, but the group2 markers are still rendered above group group1.

Comment: Could you please share more code to understand the issue. 
Is getZIndex () method retrieves the z-index of the given object ?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport, i added some more code, hope this helps. When i am comparing the z-index like so `group2.compareZOrder(group1)` i am getting -10. The `getZIndex()` also returns the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the rendering order is inverted compared to the html rendering order. If you have a look at their code example at https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/markers/ordering-overlapping-markers you will notice that clicking a marker moves it to the back although its zIndex gets increased.

So try switching your numbers:

```
const group1 = new H.map.Group({zIndex: 0});
const group2 = new H.map.Group({zIndex: 10});
```

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the case, the order is backward from DOM rendering order zindex.  They probably shouldn't have called it zIndex.